# How do I implement a list for a website that expands as well as linking to another page while closing all other lists?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement a list along the side of the website I am creating that acts similarly to the one here: http://www.boeing.com/boeing/companyoffices/aboutus/index.page? . I want each element of my list to be a link to its correlating page and to expand a sub list while also collapsing the list that was previously expanded. For example, on the boeing website I provided, if you click tours it brings you to the tours page and opens a small menu below the tours link. If you then click history, it brings you to the history page and opens the menu beneath history while closing the menu beneath tours. I am still very new to website design in general and any help would be much appreciated!

edit:

i created a list however it does not expand when i am on the correct page. instead it brings me to the correct page but sometimes removes some of the top level li items. for example, clicking on 2201 will bring me to the 2201 page but will make the 5516 or 5522 button disappear. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the unordered list i created:

```
    <div id="propertyList">
        <ul>

            <li><a href="index.html"><img src="../images/buttons/bn_home.png" width="200" height="38" alt=""/></a></li>

            <li>
                <a href="2200.html"><img src="../images/buttons/bn_2200.png" width="200" height="38" alt=""/></a>
                <ul class="2200">
                    <li>Description</li>
                    <li>Gallery</li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="3603.html"><img src="../images/buttons/bn_3603.png" width="200" height="38" alt=""/></a>
                <ul class="3603">
                    <li>Description</li>
                    <li>Gallery</li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="3615.html"><img src="../images/buttons/bn_3615.png" width="200" height="38" alt=""/></a>
                <ul class="3615">
                    <li>Description</li>
                    <li>Gallery</li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="2201.html"><img src="../images/buttons/bn_2201.png" width="200" height="38" alt=""/></a>
                <ul class="2201">
                    <li>Description</li>
                    <li>Gallery</li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="5516.html"><img src="../images/buttons/bn_5516.png" width="200" height="38" alt=""/></a>
                <ul class="5516">
                    <li>Description</li>
                    <li>Gallery</li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="5522.html"><img src="../images/buttons/bn_5522.png" width="200" height="38" alt=""/></a>
                <ul>
                    <li>Description</li>
                    <li>Gallery</li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

here is the corresponding css file:

```
    @charset "utf-8";

    #propertyList {
            width:200px;
            float:left;
    }

    #propertyList ul {
        list-style-type:none;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }

    #propertyList ul ul li {
        font-size:20px;
        color:#ffcc00;
        margin-left:15px;
        background-color:#a5a5a5;
    }

    #propertyList ul ul {
        display:none;
    }

body.2200 #propertyList ul ul.2200, body.2201 #propertyList ul ul.2201, body.3603 #propertyList ul ul.3603, body.3615 #propertyList ul ul.3615, body.5516 #propertyList ul ul.5516, body.5522 #propertyList ul ul.5522{display:block}
```

Comment: A basic google search of "css menu tutorials" should be enough and will learn you more than any answer to your problem.

Comment: Css menu tutorials wasn't specific enough as I wasnt getting the right kind of menus I wanted. Thanks Andy. I wasn't exactly sure about what the menu I was trying to create was called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on the comments you have received (unfortunately, I don't have enough room to make this a comment), you may want to take a look at the source code for that menu. When none of the menus are expanded (ie - http://www.boeing.com/boeing/companyoffices/aboutus/index.page?), the source starts like this:

```
<div class="locNavLinks0_o">
  <a href="/boeing/companyoffices/aboutus/index.page?" target="">About Us</a>
</div>
  <div class="locNavLinks1_c">
    <a href="/boeing/companyoffices/aboutus/brief.page" target="">General Information</a>
  </div>
```

...

Then, if you click on the 'General Information' link, you navigate to a new page (in this case, http://www.boeing.com/boeing/companyoffices/aboutus/brief.page) and the source changes like this:

```
  <div class="locNavLinks0_o">
    <a href="/boeing/companyoffices/aboutus/index.page?" target="">About Us</a>
  </div>
    <div class="locNavLinks1_o">
      <a href="/boeing/companyoffices/aboutus/brief.page" target="">General Information</a>
    </div>
      <div class="locNavLinks2_o_s">Boeing in Brief</div>
        <div class="locNavLinks3">
          <a href="/boeing/companyoffices/aboutus/brief/bcc.page?" target="">Boeing Capital</a>
        </div>
        <div class="locNavLinks3">
          <a href="/boeing/companyoffices/aboutus/brief/commercial.page?" target="">Commercial Airplanes</a>
        </div>
        <div class="locNavLinks3">
          <a href="/boeing/companyoffices/aboutus/brief/bds.page?" target="">Defense, Space and Security</a>
        </div>
      <div class="locNavLinks2">
        <a href="/boeing/companyoffices/aboutus/whq/index.page?" target="">Boeing Corporate</a>
      </div>
      <div class="locNavLinks2_c">
        <a href="/boeing/aboutus/employment/employment_table.page?" target="">Employment Table</a>
      </div>
```

Do you notice how they add new classes (plus new content) when the new page loads to represent the different levels of the list? Because of this, they can add new CSS rules to each individual sub-level. There are a few different ways that you can pull off this effect [for example, you could use unordered lists (<ul>)], but if you spend some time looking at this page with a good quality DOM inspector, this effect will make sense.

If you don't know what a DOM inspector is, or how you use it, if you use Chrome or Firefox, you can right click and select "Inspect element". If you use another browser, let me know and I can try to point you to another option.

Comment: So i updated my questions with the ul i have created as well as the corresponding css file. I mainly got the info for this from http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/building-a-css-vertical-expanding-menu-with-flyouts-stage-2/. i was wondering if you could tell me why my code fails to expand the menu when i am on the correct page. My menus fail to do anything at all except bring me to the correct page but some of the links actually collapse top level menu items so for example clicking on li 2201 might make 5516 and 5522 disappear

Comment: i see what they did with all the new div tags instead of using a list. thanks for all the help so far!